# Understanding the concept and existence of third-party client-side cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I have been researching types of cookies and have a question regarding client-side cookies. I understand that cookies created via JavaScript are tied to the domain they are created on, and are referred to as client-side 1st party cookies. This mechanism also applies to cookies set by external domains like Google Analytics, categorizing them as 1st party client-side cookies. What eludes me is the concept of third-party client-side cookies. From the term “third-party”, I assume that the domain specified in the cookie is different from the domain being browsed. When creating such a cookie in JavaScript using document.cookie, I believe one would need to explicitly set a different domain using the domain attribute. However, I think the browser would reject this, and even if the cookie is created, it wouldn’t be stored in the browser. My question is, while third-party client-side cookies exist as a concept, do they actually exist in practice, or is my understanding correct that they do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, **all** cookies are client-side.  That's basically the definition of a cookie, and the reason for their existence.

Third-party cookies work like this:

1. Origin site (`www.example.com`) loads an ad script from the ad server origin (`ads.example.com`).
2. Ad script may be initialized with some data, like an advertiser ID, information from the page, etc.  Then, it can send this data off to the ad server (`ads.example.com`) for logging and building a history.
3. Ad server (`ads.example.com`) may send back a cookie for future requests to `ads.example.com`, and that cookie might contain some sort of client ID.

Now, so far this only affects `www.example.com`.  But what if `other-site.example.com` wants to also have ads?

4. `other-site.example.com` loads the same ad script from `ads.example.com`.
5. The ad script can associate this new site's identity with the previous site because requests it makes can have a cookie for `ads.example.com`.
6. Ad server (`ads.example.com`) now knows data from two sites, and builds this profile on the user.

Basically, through cooperation, a user can be tracked from site to site to site.

Now, using cookies in this way is rapidly changing.  Due to a bunch of hype and hoopla, it's now considered a legal liability for ad networks (and others) to track people in this way.  Browsers are disabling third-party cookie capability by default.

Note that preventing third-party cookies doesn't actually prevent bad actors from sharing data and tracking you from site to site.  There are at least a dozen alternative methods.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful response. It has clarified the mechanism of how third-party cookies operate. I have an additional query based on my understanding: I perceive client-side cookies to be generated by client-side JavaScript, while server-side cookies are received from external servers via HTTP headers in requests. In this context, I believe the impact of Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP) pertains to client-side cookies. Is my understanding correct?